# Include empty values in a list according to specific positions (Python)

Tags: python, list, position, find, missing-data

I have the following list:

```
CompleteList=['00:00:00', '00:00:01', '00:00:02', '00:00:03',....,'23:59:59']
```

and I also have the following list:

```
IncompleteList=['00:00:00', '00:00:01', '00:00:03',....,'23:59:59']
```

As it can be seen the CompleteList has values that are missing in the IncompleteList, as for example value '00:00:02'.

I also have a third array:

```
MyList=['22', '33', '25',....,'13']
```

What I need is to include empty values in MyList in those position where IncompleteList has missing values in the following way:

```
MyList_result=['22', '33','','25',....,'13']
```

I have achieved this in the following way:

```
MyList_result=[]

for item in CompleteList:
    if item in IncompleteList:
        ind=IncompleteList.index(item)   
        v=MyList[ind]
        MyList_result.append(v)

    else:
        v=''
        MyList_result.append(v)
```

This works but it takes too long taking into account the size of the lists that I am working with. I really need to find a more efficient way of doing it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can we assume that `CompleteList` and `IncompleteList` are sorted?

Comment: @sanchitarora: Yes... I think they are sorted as the elements that they both contain are times, but does this affect?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first intuitive approach would be to convert the `IncompleteList` to a set and get an iterator for `MyList`. Then it becomes a linear operation in iterating over `CompleteList` and spit out the next item from the `MyList` iterator if the elem from `CompleteList` is present in `IncompleteList` else as per your example an empty string

**Sample Code**

```
IncompleteList=['00:00:00', '00:00:01', '00:00:03','23:59:59']
IncompleteSet = set(IncompleteList)
MyList=['22', '33', '25','13']
CompleteList=['00:00:00', '00:00:01', '00:00:02', '00:00:03','23:59:59']
MyListIt = iter(MyList)
[next(MyListIt) if cl_elem in IncompleteSet else '' for cl_elem in CompleteList]
```

**Sample Output**

```
Out[100]: ['22', '33', '', '25', '13']
```

Alternatively you can zip both the `IncompleteList` and `MyList` and convert the paired list as a dictionary. Following which iterate over the `CompleteList` and spit out the corresponding value from the dictionary if the element is present else an empty string

```
MyDict = dict(zip(IncompleteList, MyList))

[MyDict.get(k, '') for k in CompleteList]
Out[108]: ['22', '33', '', '25', '13']
```

Answer (score 1):

The bottleneck from your implementation is in two places:

- You are checking for each item from the `CompleteList` in the `IncompleteList` at

  ```
  if item in IncompleteList:
  ```

  which in the worst case would scan the `IncompleteList` `n` number of times (if `n` is the number of elements in the `CompleteList`)
- If the item is present you find the index of the item at

  ```
  ind = IncompleteList.index(item)
  ```

  which involves another scan of the `IncompleteList`

The first solution suggested by @Abhijit solves the second problem where you do not have to scan the list a second time to get the index. However the check for the presence of the item in the `IncompleteList`/`IncompleteSet` is still a bottleneck.

If we can assume sorted lists then the following solution will be faster although a little more complex:

```
MyList_result = []
incomplete_list_index = 0
incomplete_list_length = len(IncompleteList)
for item in CompleteList:
    if incomplete_list_index < incomplete_list_length and IncompleteList[incomplete_list_index] == item:
        MyList_result.append(MyList[incomplete_list_index])
        incomplete_list_index += 1
    else:
        MyList_result.append('')
```

This involves just a single pass of the `CompleteList` (and no pre-processing to generate a Dict as the second solution suggested by @Abhijit).

Comment: @sanchitatora: I have just noticed that something is wrong with this method. Apparently, this method will miss values at the end of MyList array. What I mean is that the result that I would obtain with this method would be: MyList_result=['22', '33', '', '25'] and not ['22', '33', '', '25,'13']. For some reason, for each empty value I include in the array, I get one value less at the end of the list.

Comment: @Sarah I tested the solution with a sample input similar to the one you provided and it does not miss any values. You can check the results here - http://pastebin.com/D52jU4vH - I would like to fix the issues if any in case someone else comes here and wants to test/use the solution.

Comment: @sanchitatora: Yes, you are right, this method seems to work fine and even a tiny bit faster than the other suggested methods. I do not know why I got that problem before. I will be testing it further and if I find why I had that issue I will post it here.

Comment: @sanchitatora: I have found an issue for example if I consider the following case: CompleteList=['00:00:00', '00:00:01', '00:00:02', '00:00:03','23:59:59'], IncompleteList=['00:00:00', '00:00:01','00:00:02'] and MyList=['22','33','25']. Its says that the list index is out of range?.

Comment: @Sarah Fixed. I had missed an edge case.